# Lyaponov function in dynamic system (in polar cordonates)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Let the following system in $R^2$
\begin{equation}
(S) \left\{
\begin{array}{l c }
\overset{.}{\rho}=\rho(1-\rho) \\
\overset{.}{\theta}=\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
study the stability of the point $(0,0)$ ?
in particular i search the Lyaponov function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What are your thoughts?  Where are you stuck?  Incidentally, you don't need to find a Lyapunov function to conclude that the origin is unstable.

Comment: @user539887 well, then stationnary point  $(0,0)$ is unstable (locally), but with lyapunov function we can see things ( globally ).

Comment: @Anas In general, yes, but the system considered by the OP is already decoupled in polar coordinates, so the use of Lyapunov function seems to be redundant here.

Comment: yes, and how to shown that (0.0) unstable, because we did 3 method to show the stability of a point, Lyaponov 1, 2 and Lyaponov La Salle, also linearization, but it does not work here

Comment: Take a point $(x_0,y_0)$ with $r_0=\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\in(0,1)$. Applying separation of variables to the $r$-equation we get that $r(t)=r_0e^{t}/(1-r_0+r_0e^t)$, where $r(t)=\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}$. Can you conclude now that the equilibrium $(0,0)$ is (Lyapunov) unstable?

Comment: Incidentally, there is a discussion of a system with the same phase portrait going on: [Requirement of Lyapunov Stability in Asymptotic Stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190952/requirement-of-lyapunov-stability-in-asymptotic-stability).

Comment: I did it by definition, thanks