# Filippov dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following system of differential equations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in polar coordinates: 
\begin{cases}
 \dot{\rho}=\rho(1-\rho) & \text{ (i)}\\ 
 \dot{\theta}=\sin^{2}\left ( \frac{\theta}{2} \right ) & \text{ (ii) } 
\end{cases}
My question is: how can I study the equation $(i)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, and the equation $(ii)$ on $[0,2\pi]$? More precisely: how can I study the asymptotic behavior of the solutions and their orbits?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A duplicate of [Lyaponov function in dynamic system (in polar cordonates)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191798/lyaponov-function-in-dynamic-system-in-polar-cordonates#comment6571520_3191798). You can also see a related (however, not  the same) system in the answer to [Requirement of Lyapunov Stability in Asymptotic Stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190952/requirement-of-lyapunov-stability-in-asymptotic-stability/3191087#3191087).

Comment: Incidentally, why Fillippov?  To me, A. F. Filippov's name is associated with ODEs systems with *non-continuous* RHSs.

Comment: Scalar dynamics on the real line or the positive ray are easy to analyze. Just look at the roots of the right side (stationary points) and the sign of it in the intervals between them (monotonicity).

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions .