# Example of unstable attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

While defining the notion of assymptotically stable solution of an ODE (stable + atractor), my notes warn that there are unstable attractors and accompany this with the following diagram:

[image]

What is a simple example of an unstable attractor.

Comment: Please refer [Unstable attractor](http://www.nld.ds.mpg.de/downloads/paper/timme2005.pdf), in which you can see the definition of an unstable attractor in page 3 and an example of an unstable attractor in Piecewise Smooth Map in page 5, hope this helps. Also a not so active chat room on [Dynamical Systems and Chaos theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory)

Comment: For an example, see, e.g.. [Requirement of Lyapunov Stability in Asymptotic Stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190952/requirement-of-lyapunov-stability-in-asymptotic-stability/3191087#3191087).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unstable attractor $A$ essentially is an invariant set with a basin of attraction containing a positive measure set and for all neighborhoods $U(A)$, a positive Lebesgue measure of points leave that neighborhood $U(A)$. A simple example is provided by a dynamical system defined via the differential equation

$$\frac{d x}{d t} = x^2 +I $$, where $x,I \in \mathbb{R}$.

At $I>0$ there is no fixed point, at $I<0$ there are two fixed points, and at $I=0$ there is one "half-stable" fixed point at $x=0$, such that trajectories starting from initial conditions $x(0)<0$ converge towards it and  trajectories starting from initial conditions $x(0)>0$ diverge from it. Thus the  basin of attraction contains a positive measure set $[-1,0)$ and at the same time, every neighborhood intersects with the positive real line, so a positive measure subset leaves the neighborhood.

Here not the full measure of points of a neighborhood leave it. Such a setting is impossible for sufficiently smooth right hand sides of ordinary (non-delayed) differential equations, but it may exist for maps, as illustrated in the UNSTABLE ATTRACTOR reference provided by Baymax.

The original work on attractors that may be unstable is by John Milnor, On the Concept of attractors, Communications in Mathematical Physics 1985, 
https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01212280