# Can an equilibrium be unstable and asymptotically stable at the same time?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, definition, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the autonomous dynamical system,
$$\dot x = f(x)$$

An equilibrium $p$, ($f(p) = 0$), is unstable in the sense of Lyapunov means:

$\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists some $x(0)$, whenever $\|x(0) - p\| < \delta$, $\|x(t) - p\| \geq \epsilon$ for some time $t$.

---

Since $x(t)$ only escapes the $\epsilon$ ball for some time $t$, but may come back in the future and even converge towards $p$, therefore can the equilibrium $p$ be simultaneously unstable and asymptotically stable?

---

I guess the correct definition of unstable should say: $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists some $x(0)$, whenever $\|x(0) - p\| < \delta$, there exists some $t_0$ such that $\|x(t) - p\| > \epsilon$ for ALL time $t \geq t_0$.

But this is not the negation of stable in the sense of Lyapunov (Recall stable in the sense of Lyapunov means $\|x(t) - p\| < \epsilon$ for all time $t$. Therefore the negation of this condition is $\|x(t) - p\| \geq \epsilon$ for some $t$. But this says nothing about the limiting behavior of $x(t)$.)

Comment: Do you have a source for this Lyapunov instability requirement? Namely, I believe using this one can show that any system is "unstable" by picking $\epsilon$ arbitrarily close to zero. Maybe a better check for an unstable equilibrium is [Chetaev instability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Page 13, question 2: https://www.control.tf.uni-kiel.de/en/teaching/summer-term/applied-nonlinear-dynamics/fileadmin/exercises/and_ex2020

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen The common definition is that an equilibrium is unstable if it is NOT stable. Therefore, unstable is simply the negation of the stable definition.

Comment: @Fraïssé Note that mere convergence to $p$ is not sufficient for stability since solutions may have finite escape time. So absolutely can you have instability even though in the long run the solution converges (such a system is called "convergent", but not "stable"). I think it is quite intuitive to not call such a system stable.

Comment: @Fraïssé One can't just change the inequality direction from Lyapunov stability to obtain a criteria for instability. Because if there is an $\epsilon$ such that $\|x(t) - p\| \geq \epsilon$, then this does not rule out that there is also an $\epsilon$ such that $\|x(t) - p\| <\epsilon,\ \forall\ t\geq0$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Could you provide a definition of unstable in terms of $\epsilon-\delta$ as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot. By definition, an equilibrium point is asymptotically stable if it is both stable and attractive. Therefore, if the equilibrium point is unstable, it cannot be asymptotically stable.

However, the equilibrium point can be attractive without being stable. For instance, the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ of the system
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x}&=&x^2-y^2\\
\dot{y}&=&2xy
\end{array}
$$
exhibits such a property.

Your definition of unstable exclude attractivity, while the standard one allows for it. The definition of a stable equilibrium point $p$ in the sense of Lyapunov is

$$
\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0: ||x_0-p||\le\delta \Rightarrow \forall t\ge0:||x(t)-p||\le\epsilon.
$$

In this regard, the definition of a unstable (or not-stable) equilibrium point $p$ in the sense of Lyapunov is given by the negation of the above statement:

$$
\exists \epsilon>0,\forall \delta>0: ||x_0-p||\le\delta \Rightarrow \exists t\ge0: ||x(t)-p||>\epsilon.
$$

Comment: I think in your negation of stability you are missing an important part after the first colon: 'there exists $x_0$ such that ...' Otherwise it could be understood, as in the definition of stability, as 'for every $x_0$ such that' which is a much stronger statement. For Lyapunov unstable it is enough that some orbits can leave the neighbourhood, not all orbits

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but in the answer of KBS, there is a typo...so I would like to comment...in the example of attractive but unstable equilibrium, the point (0,0) is only ``almost attractive'' i.e. attractive for almost all initial conditions, since on the half-line $y=0, x>0$ the solution are exploding (in finite time!)...probably putting $-\text{sgn}(x)x^2$ instead of $x^2$ in the first state equation should provide an example of attractive but unstable point, but this should be checked!..In any case there are many examples of such systems, e.g. [Requirement of Lyapunov Stability in Asymptotic Stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190952/requirement-of-lyapunov-stability-in-asymptotic-stability/3191087#3191087)