Critical point that is attractive but unstable
Suppose we have an ODE $\dot{x}=F(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $x_0$ is a critical point of it. $x_0$ is said attractive if $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. for any $y_0 \in B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$, the solution curve starting at $y_0$, denoted by $x(t,y_0)$, satisfies $\lim_t x(t,y_0)=x_0$.
My question: Can someone give an example that $x_0$ is a critical point, which is attractive but unstable? I can imagine what the phase portrait looks like: The solution curve starting near $x_0$ first goes away from it and then comes back after some time. It is unstable because the stability requires the solution curve to stay close to $x_0$ for all time.
Thanks in advance.

One way I can envision this happening is via a homoclinic orbit at $x_0$ that encloses a linearly unstable critical point. Since we are in the plane, this orbit partitions the plane into interior and exterior sets. The exterior points can converge to the stable manifold of $x_0$ and the interior points can be repelled by the unstable critical point towards the homoclinic orbit which itself converges to $x_0$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3191087/1242
